# Google Calendar API event recurrence how to "change/delete this and all following events"

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am trying to use the Calendar API (v3) to do what Google Calendar does when a user clicks the middle option here:

[image: Edit recurring event]

Examining the data in API Explorer, it appears that Google essentially splits the series at the event time: it truncates the existing series (sets the RRULE UNTIL clause) and creates a new identical series, adjusting the RRULE COUNT clause if given.

The key piece of magic in this is that past instances of the original series are not re-created, i.e. instance-specific state is not lost.

I don't see how this is possible using the API, since any change to recurrence triggers re-creation of the entire series, and you lose any instance-specific state; but yet you have to modify the RRULE UNTIL clause.

Is there some way to modify an element of a RRULE without triggering re-creation of the series? Or some other way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: I did some tests, and I don't find that changing the recurrence settings of an event causes the instance-specific changes to be lost. Can you go into more detail about your process and the results you are seeing?

Comment: Hi Eric, if I understood your question correctly, you mind find an answer in this blogpost: http://googledevelopers.blogspot.ch/2013/12/changes-to-all-following-behavior-in.html The short version is that this behavior is not currently available in the API (only through cutting the tail off with UNTIL and creating a new event).